# Does it makes sense to have multiple tags for each dialect

Tags: discussion, tags

The Japanese language can vary significantly between dialects and the answers to some questions can actually be different depending on what dialect it is referred to.

for instance the major ones would be
Okinawa
Kansai
Standard (Tokyo)

My main concern is would we limit it each prefecture or would we limit it to just the few major dialects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if there is no tag then it should be understood that the question applies to standard Japanese and be answered accordingly, but if someone notes otherwise, then it should apply to a give dialect. A tag would be the best way to note the dialect(s)