# Should tags be completely in English "Osaka-ben"

Tags: discussion, tags

This is a continuation of the people question, but also applies to other tags in general

[Does it makes sense to have multiple tags for each dialect](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/does-it-makes-sense-to-have-multiple-tags-for-each-dialect)

Should tags like "Osaka-ben" be changed to something like "Osaka-Dialect" or should we make them more atomic and do two tags to a question like "Dialect" and "Osaka"?

my main concern is that new-comers to japanese aren't going to know that Osaka-ben means Osaka dialect.

My recommendation would be to have two tags "Osaka" and "Dialect" to gives us the most flexibility.  Though i worry that people will see the "Osaka" tag and start adding all kinds of cities.

Comment: Or maybe: eg, 'dialect-osaka' for specific dialects, and 'dialect' for general dialect questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this situation is best dealt with by `tag synonyms`. Let people tag them whichever way feels natural to them for a while, then choose the most popular one as the main tag and any equivalent ones as synonyms of them.

This would apply to each dialect where such a situation arises. Yesterday I tagged one question as `dialects` and `yamagata-ben` for instance.

Comment: Totally agree.  "something-ben" becomes pretty natural to say when discussing with other learners, as opposed to "something dialect".  Let the tag synonym handle it.

Answer (score 3):

Having encountered this type of problem elsewhere, it looks like adding tag wikis would also go far in disambiguating meanings - either before or after they are communally established.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [hippietrail's answer](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/should-tags-be-completely-in-english-osaka-ben/80#80), I think we should also use synonyms.  But instead of picking the most popular tag, use the -ben version as the main tag and the -dialect version as a synonym.  That way it sounds more natural for most people, and new people might even learn what -ben means.

Comment: I also prefer the -ben versions but didn't anticipate what the rest of the community might prefer.